# Chrome instance ID, what is it exactly?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm reading the documentation for [`chrome.instanceID`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/instanceID/#method-getID), but I'm still confused. According to the documentation, it returns

> An Instance ID assigned to the app instance".

However, I'm not sure what exactly is meant by the term "app instance".

Specifically, I have the following questions:

- Does this term refer to a running extension, a browser window, or something else?
- Will the Instance ID change if Chrome is restarted?
- Will the Instance ID change if another user (with a different Google profile) opens a new Chrome window?

Comment: Have you read this already? [What is Instance ID?](https://developers.google.com/instance-id)

Comment: Thanks for putting the link, it's useful but doesn't answer my questions directly. From the description, it seems like an Instance ID is for describing and differentiating `(device, user, app)`, but it also says `Your app can request a fresh InstanceID whenever needed using the getID() method`, which feels like the ID could be different every time it's requested on the same `(device, user, app)`